# Convert nb.FormClosed += (s, ex) => to C++ CLI

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I want to convert this

```
nb.FormClosed += (s, ex) =>
(overriding OnClose form method)
```

to C++ CLI. I was trying something like .override but can't find correct C++CLI variant of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't override OnClose. That adds an event listener to the FormClosed event.

C++/CLI doesn't support lambda expressions. You'll need to subscribe with a real method. You'll also need to initialize the delegate instance explicitly. Here's the basic syntax:

```
nb->FormClosed += gcnew FormClosedEventHandler(this, &ClassName::MyCloseHandler)
```